# Renaming the folder which contains my .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

so I’ve been trying to rename a old project that I had been working on but every time I rename the folder that contains my csproj it won’t load and asks to load the the file with the folder name

My old project was Metroloader/Metroloader.csproj

The thing I want to change it to is Nutsloader/Nutsloader.csproj

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Solution
2. Rename folder
3. Open solution
4. Remove not loaded project from solution
   [image]
5. Add existing project from new location:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit .sln file and provide correct folder path to your renamed .csproj

Comment: @CocoKek Of course it worked, because it is appropriate way to do it, I just hint you shortcut to do the same :)